# RAILS: Don't create new record if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically what i need is just method (probably before_create filter) performed when creating new record to check if record with such a title exists (case insensitive) and if it is exists - return finded record and don't create new. If not - create new record.

**It is NOT simple `exists?` check. I have nested form with 9 association. I need method that would be executed before creating record and preform action like i described in topic, so i can reffer that action to each of associated model**

Thank you.

Comment: @Vucko It is not that easy, because i have nested form with 9 association. I need method that would be executed before creating record and preform action like i described in topic, so i can reffer that action to each of associated model

Comment: Please update your questions with more details about the "9 associations". If you leave out information on your questions the responses you get won't match your expectations. Creating 9 associated objects at once might be the issue, but you might have valid reasons to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `find_or_create_by`. [See Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

Since your data model seems fairly complex you may want to use it in conjunction with a form object: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit.

If this is not the answer please post a bit more code and we can help you through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Action**

```
@existing = Records.where('title = ?', params[:title]).first
if @existing.present?

record_path(@existing)

create action
```

end

Comment: It is not that easy, because i have nested form with 9 association. I need method that would be executed before creating record and preform action like i described in topic.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work like this, he won't create the record if he already exists with this method. However you can use this exact method as a before_filter anyway in the Record.rb

Comment: It is kinda not right to write 4 lines of same code to all 9 models. Coul'd you imagine 4x9=36 lines of code doing same thing just for different models?

Comment: well why dont you create a method that does this for all the associations and if it doesnt exist in any association it returns false if it exists in at least one it returns true, then you just have to make that validation on the create action. Like

 if Record.yourfunction(record) does nothing
else
creates

Comment: It is possible, but still not a right way (as i feel) of doin'g that. I still need to list all of the association and it's values to the method in controller. Can't be done by each method because of the model names...

Comment: No. I mean creating a global helper. Then in the controller all you have to do is call that helper

Comment: what do you mean, i have incomeing params array with different models attributes. i need to select those attributes for different models and then check it...

Comment: then you have to make that check on Create action... if you need the params to check  it must be in create

Comment: ofcourse, but i don't want to write same lines of code for each model. That is my main goal

Comment: Rails 4 has the concept of 'concerns' - this where you can write shared model code http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html. It might be worth exploring.